# Single block of code (multi-line) - Exception highlights all of it. Where is the error?

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio, exception

From times to times I face myself with a big linq block of code that is crashing from some different reasons, NULL properties / etc...
The following code is a representation of these blocks of code.

```
var myObj = new Something {
      Pro1 = somethingElse.P1,
      Pro2 = somethingElse.P2,
      Pro3 = (from x in db.something
              let y = ...
              let z = ...
              where  <condition1>
              && <condition2>
              && ...
             select new SomethingElseAsWell{
                 A = x.B.C.Prop1,
                 B = y
                 C = x.Sssss
                 ...
             }
}
```

But what is annoying is the fact that at first sight I simple do not know the exact line that is causing my exception, visual studio is just giving me a generic error that could be happening in several lines.

Then as always I need to "break" the code in to several independent lines and run until I know exactly the line that is causing the problem. However this steps are annoying and may take a while.

My question is: **is there a faster and simpler solution to find this kind of mistakes**?

Comment: What exactly is this "generic error"? With care you may find it's not as generic as you think, but we can't tell without knowing what it is.

Comment: The exception can be from type: NULL can not be compared to bool, or "property" is Null, any kind of exception. My issue is that the exception highlights ALL the code and not the exact line that is causing the issue.

Comment: Well the exception will have *a* line number within your code. Just because Visual Studio highlights a whole statement doesn't mean there isn't useful information within the exception.

Comment: @JonSkeet Nop, there is NO information about the line number in the exception View Detail window.

Comment: Even in a debug build? That sounds very strange to me. I've never seen a debug build (with normal settings) not give line numbers in exceptions for user code.

Comment: @JonSkeet Using VS2010 (running in debug) when the execution hits that code and throws the exception, all the code (ALL the lines) are highlighted, then the "small" exception window happears and the "visual line" connects the code from the first line to the exception window. Gives me a generic error (depends the type like I said) but even if the exact line is the last one, does not matter, there is no visual information for that (neither any field from the exception is telling me the line number of it).

Comment: This is the price of heavy syntax sugar, the generated code is *very* different and looks little like the original C# statement.  So they punted the debug info for the generated code, attributing it all to a single statement in your source code file.  All you can reasonably do to get better debug info is to rewrite it and use explicit Linq extension methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting feedback from several sources using VS2010 (probably other versions as well), the only solution for now is really "rewrite" that piece of code as I've being doing to know exactly where is the problem.

If meanwhile someone finds an easier way, please fell free to share it.